# when downloading certficate binary data , result is invalid certificate

Tags: php, download, binary, certificate, xxd

I'm receiving binary data in php as certificate content and I want to download it to browser .
I'm getting this message always when opening it with certificate viewer :

> ```
> hex(19).pfx
> Could not display 'hex(19).pfx'
> Reason:   Unrecognized or unsupported data.
> ```

this binary data is correct , I put it in a file on the server immediately and it made a valid certificate .

I think the problem is in two where :

- output of command

  `exec('ssh root@192.168.0.137 "echo '.$bindata.' | xxd -p -r | tr -d \'\n\' "',$output);`

while `$bindata` is coming from converting certificate pfx file after making it in bash with `xxd -p`

- or it's in the header , there is a lost or addition :

  ```
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hex.pfx");
  header('Content-Length: '.  strlen($output[0]));
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  echo $output[0];
  exit();
  ```

  what's the wrong ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the exec command?

Comment: I wrote in the question that I want to convert back my certificate from hex to bin to give it then to browser .

Comment: That seems like an awful lot of (costly) redirections for doing just that. Could be that a simple `pack('H*', $hexstr);` does the same. Where do you get the hex string from and what's really "in" it? An x509 certificate in pem/der format, a (complete) p12/pfx, ...?

Comment: actually I used `xxd` in bash to convert it from bin to hex , so I re-used it in php to convert it bash to bin and give it to browser . 
since  p12/pfx is binary and can't be output of bash without converting it to hex .

Comment: you can read my scenario in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145651/download-binary-stream-data-from-browser-using-php-with-web-service-downloaded)

Comment: So your premise is `since p12/pfx is binary and can't be output of bash without converting it to hex`. And then you try using a remote shell (bash again?) to do the hex to bin conversion? ;-) Anyway, when you write "bash" you mean "openssl via command line"?

Comment: exactly , I wrote a bash with the help of OpenSSL to generate certificates .

Comment: @VolkerK so , can you help me plz !? I've been trying since yesterday and nothing works with it :(

Comment: `hexdump -b $exportedcert`, you already have the cert/p12 data in a file within the file system?

Comment: no, I don't . I delete all generated files after putting result in a variable . this command is not the solution `xxd` does the same job . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is to remove spaces of the output of xxd

in bash :

```
res=`xxd -p $exportedkey`
echo "${res//[[:space:]]/}"
```

in php :

```
$hex = hex2bin($result);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hex.pfx");
header('Content-Length: '.  strlen($hex));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

echo $hex;
exit();
```

hope it helps at least someone